# fork and execlp

Tags: linux, fork

When I use fork to create a new child process and then call execlp syscall to run a new program in the child. The process ids that I get in the child process after execlp and I get from waitpid syscall after the child terminates are different.

For example, getpid() returns 7103 in the child and waitpid returns 7101 in the parent.

I guess something happens after execlp runs. Can anyone explain this. Thanks.

BTW, I run my code on Fedora.

Here is the code:

/*  program parent  */

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0){
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(2);
}

if (pid == 0){
    // child
    execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-e", "./echo_cli", "127.0.0.1", (char *)0);
    exit(0);
}
/* ... */
// sig_chld handles SIGCHLD singal
void sig_chld(int signo){
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;

    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0){ 
        printf("Child %d terminated\n", pid);
    }   
    return ;
}
```

/* program echo_cli */

```
pid = getpid();
```

Comment: Not without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: the pid in echo_cli and the pid returned by waitpid are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing `xterm`, not `echo_cli`. Your child's child will of course report a different PID.

Comment: Execute `echo_cli` directly instead of asking `xterm` to do so.

Comment: Well, the assignment says I need to use xterm to pop up a x-window.

Comment: Then you can't know `echo_cli`'s PID directly.

Comment: I see. Maybe I can pass the pid in execlp to resolve this problem. Thanks anyway.